# WordPress twentytwenty theme child css not effective

Tags: wordpress, child-theming, twentytwenty

I followed all the instructions to create my child theme. In functions.php, I have:

```
<?php

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tt_child_enqueue_parent_styles' );

    function tt_child_enqueue_parent_styles() {
       wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
    }

?>
```

In style.css, i have correct header comment part:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Twenty Twenty Child
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-twenty-child/
 Description:  Twenty Twenty Child Theme
 Author:       X Y
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     twentytwenty
 Version:      1.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  twentytwentychild
*/

h1 {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

However, seems the child style.css don't work, no effect. In the page HTML code, below lines show and look correct:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='parent-style-css'  href='https://lifepromise.co.uk/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/style.css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentytwenty-style-css'  href='https://lifepromise.co.uk/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty-child/style.css' media='all' />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code on function.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tt_child_enqueue_parent_styles' );

function tt_child_enqueue_parent_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwenty-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css', array('twentytwenty-style') );
}
```

Tested and working

Comment: No effect, the child style is still loaded after the template one.

Comment: Do you want to load child style before the parent style?

Comment: No, I want child style to take effect last.